# How to sell comic books through Apple in-app purchase?

Tags: app-store-connect, in-app-purchase

I am working on a comic reader app which is almost same as other panel by panel readers. I planned to provide authors with a web interface where from they would be able to upload their contents and fix a price. But going through several articles, it seemed like Apple doesn't work in that way. Now I need to know, how can I provide a functionality like this. I was planning to collect all the books from the authors and login to Apple's portal to upload those books. But then also there is a restriction of 10k products on Apple's portal. I was wondering how giants like DC, Marvel or Comixology have overcame this. To be precise, I need to know if I want to achieve functionalities of comic selling as of Comixology, what approach should I follow to upload comics to store. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Apple thoroughly documents the requirements for participating in their stores at the developer website:

https://developer.apple.com/resources/

You should review the iBooks and In-App Purchase from the above page.

At that point, you should be ready to read and digest the actual App Store Resources themselves to figure out what sort of effort you'll need to expend to sell your content through Apple.

https://developer.apple.com/appstore/index.html

Assuming you are on iOS - you can skip the parts on the Mac App Store. The review guidelines have some of the information you'll need.